# Print HTML Table with jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, html, printing

I would to print an HTML table, with a lot of coloumns and rows in landscape mode.
But, in printing preview I can see only a part of that table.

I used this javascript to print my table

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function Print() {
  var docprint = window.open("about:blank", "_blank"); 
  var oTable = document.getElementById("mytable");
  docprint.document.open(); 
  docprint.document.write(oTable.parentNode.innerHTML);
  docprint.document.close(); 
  docprint.print();
  docprint.close();
}


</script>
```

I would to print and view the table entirely. 
Could be a chrome issue? IN Firefox table was printed correctly but without colors..

Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: A guess would be, that you miss the outer `<table>` tag with that code. Try to add it manually.

Comment: I check outer tags and it's all ok...my table contains a scroll div, perhaphs this is the problem....I set it with height: auto....but in the print preview I see a part of that table :( Please help me..

Comment: Could you maybe build a small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show your problem?

Comment: I noticed that if I set 632px as height it will print correctly but if I set height to value greater than 632px the table will cutting off in the printing preview..